# How to rewrite a url with multiple parameters to new url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have rewritten my site from asp to php. I need to redirect a few pages with multiple parameters.

These are a few of the old url's:

```
mysite.co.uk/productlist_paged.asp?cid=1&offset=10
mysite.co.uk/productlist_paged.asp?cid=1&offset=20
mysite.co.uk/productlist_paged.asp?cid=1&offset=30
mysite.co.uk/productlist_paged.asp?cid=1&offset=40
```

to the following new pages:

```
mysite.co.uk/Compare/Roland-Digital-Pianos/43/1
mysite.co.uk/Compare/Roland-Digital-Pianos/43/2
mysite.co.uk/Compare/Roland-Digital-Pianos/43/3
mysite.co.uk/Compare/Roland-Digital-Pianos/43/4
```

I was hoping to keep the number 43 out of the redirect as this a number that will change when products are added/removed. 
cid=1 equals Roland-Digital-Pianos and e.g offset=10 is number 1 at the end of the url

Any help welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with something like :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cid=1&offset=([0-9]+)0
RewriteRule ^productlist_paged.asp$ /Compare/Roland-Digital-Pianos/43/%1? [R=301,L]
```

There is an extra `0` at the end of the `RewriteCond`, otherwise, `%1` would be `10` or `20` instead of `1` or `2`.

The extra `?` at the end delete the `QUERY_STRING` in the redirect url.

Note : I didn't add the `^` and `$` in the `RewriteCond`, so that your url doesn't necessarly start/end with this `QUERY_STRING`, ie `productlist_paged.asp?test=1&cid=1&offset=10&test2=1` will also fit the `RewriteCond` and get redirected.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Glad it worked ! Note that it's not possible (or i don't know how) to handle the `43` number problem, since you can't know, when your asp url is call, what number it is.